# PHP - converting bitmask

Tags: php, bit-manipulation

Say I assign the following fruits:

`array ('1' => 'apple', '2' => 'banana', '4' => 'grape', '8' => 'orange')`

If I wanted to represent `apple` and `banana`, I could just do the following: `0001 OR 0010` to get `0011` (or 3), right?

Given the number `3`, how do I convert that to `1` and `2`?

Comment: `0001 AND 0010` is 0. Probably you mean `0001 OR 0010`

Comment: No, neither. He should be using the bit-wise `&` and `|` if anything.

Comment: FYI, it's easier to produce proper bit masks with the bitwise [shift left](http://php.net/operators.bitwise) operator: `2 << 3; // 8`

Comment: @Jonah In order to produce powers of 2, it is a lot easier to use bitshift instead of power.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All keys will be loaded into `$keys`:

```
$keys = array();
$value = 3;

foreach ($arr as $key => $val)
{
   if ($value & $key)
   {
      $keys[] = $key;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally you use bitmasks this way (language is irrelevant)

```
BANANA = 0x1
APPLE = 0x2
GRAPE = 0x4
LEMON = 0x8
PAPAYA = 0x10
GUAYABA = 0x20


myFavoriteFruits = BANANA | GRAPE // I like both bananas and grapes.
```

Now to test if I like Bananas you evalute:

```
myFavoriteFruits & BANANA
```

Answer (score 1):

use the bitwise AND (&) operator in a loop to test the bits.

Comment: looks like Tim Cooper provided one :^)